# Calculate time difference from two unix time stamps and convert to minutes in Java

Tags: java, unix

I have two *UNIX* time stamps, I want to compare them and then get the difference in minutes.

E.g. `1418600222 and 1418602180`, where `1418602180 - 1418600222` gives me an answer in minutes. I tried to google it but most of the results are in `javascript` which i have a rather limited understanding of.

Comment: Just FYI, Java and JavaScript are totally different.

Comment: @Manu yeah, i know but i'd say some times the logic can be quite similar

Comment: Honestly, use the new Date/Time API in Java 8 or JodaTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        long t1=1418602180;
        long t2=1418600222;
        long minutes=Math.abs(t1-t2)/60;
        System.out.println(minutes);
```

Comment: +1 for simplest based on what's in the question. If the OP wants to do anything more substantial, I'd use Date/Time API or JodaTime

Comment: Thank you! Just needed a simple solution like this :-) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

look at java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit#SECONDS.toMinutes()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public class tets {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    long timeStamp= 1418602180 - 1418600222;
    java.util.Date time=new java.util.Date(timeStamp*1000);
    System.out.println(time.getMinutes());
}
}
```

**OUTPUT** 2

UPDATE

In my previous example,I had used the deprecated methods. You can use joda time as below

```
LocalDateTime d1=new LocalDateTime(new Date(1418602180 *1000));
    LocalDateTime d2=new LocalDateTime(new Date(1418600222*1000));

    System.out.println(d1);
    System.out.println(d2);
    int minutesDiff=Minutes.minutesBetween(d2, d1).getMinutes();
    System.out.println(minutesDiff);
```

Comment: I doubt, very highly that will give an accurate result for differences greater then 59 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Unix timestamp (also known as epoch time) is just the number of seconds since 00:00:00 of 1970-01-01.

Given that it is a number, you can compute the difference as with any other number. You will get the difference in seconds. Divide this by 60 to get difference in minutes.

Your example:

```
1418602180 is 2014-12-15 00:09:40 GMT
1418600222 is 2014-12-14 23:37:02 GMT

difference is 1418602180 - 1418600222 = 1958 seconds
1958 / 60 = 32.6333 minutes
```